# Show content only for organic traffic

Tags: php

I want to show some content only for visitors from search engines,
can you help me please ? :)

I already have this php, but it show only for google.com but I want whole google and yahoo :)

```
if(substr((trim($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])), 0, 23) == "http://www.google.com/")
{
    echo "Show what I want";
}
```

Comment: try using `strstr` for your needs: [PHP strstr() function](http://pl1.php.net/manual/pl/function.strstr.php)

Comment: looks like duplicated from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421123/show-my-widget-only-for-organic-traffic)

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking this question again. Isn't this a duplicate? Thanks @Wilq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, consider using [stripos](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.stripos.php) as an efficient way of testing if a string contains another string:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], '.google.') !== false 
      || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], '.yahoo.') !== false) {
    echo "Show what I want";
}
```

There are plenty of variations on the google and yahoo domains (e.g. google.co.uk) so it is up to you how strict you want the matching to be.

Comment: so if I will use your code I dont have to manually add google.co.uk ? it will be for all google referrals ? Thanks anyway !

Comment: @Chymmi that's correct - it effectively just looks for either "google" or "yahoo" in the referer.